# iOS implement a long scroll view best practice

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory, uiscrollview

Hi i would to implement a very long scroll view for a forum-like view, designing something similar to this image

[image]

would it possible to implement this with a table view (considering the not very defined borders between cells and some views overlapping other cells) or i should write a long scroll view with many subviews (memory management?)?
Thanks

Comment: use UITableView simple

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fb-gallery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `UITableView`, and it would be better if you subclass `UITableViewCell` and use the `layoutSubviews` method to adjust the subviews when you adjust the size of the cell. Change the cell size according to the content present in it.

Check the below links for this:

- [iOS SDK: Crafting Custom UITableView Cells](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)
- [Customize Table View Cells for UITableView](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)
- [Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

Answer (score 3):

One piece of advise : be lazy !
if you want to present a lot of views in a scrollView, don't load them all. The best practice for this is to use a `UITableView`. If you know the height of each cell before drawing them on screen, you can implement this method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in your Tableview Datasource.
If you want to use a UIScrollView, add your subviews on demand when the user scroll. The best approach is to implement the delegate method :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

Answer (score 3):

you can make a custom `UIView` and in that you can make all that you want and simply add your custom view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as

`[cell.contentView addSubview:yourcustomview];`

the code is

```
CV = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, heightofviewyouwant)];
CV.delegate = self;
cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
[CV setTitle:[[yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"yourkey"]]; 
CV.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];   
[cell.contentView addSubview:CV]; 

return cell;
```